# How do you create a plot from two different data frames (or how do you combine data frames with identical column names)

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have two dataframes and I want to plot a comparison between them. The plot and dataframes look like so

```
df2019 <- data.frame(Institute = c("A","B","C"),Women = c(65,50,70),Men = c(35,50,30))
df2016 <- data.frame(Institute = c("A","B","C"),Women = c(70,45,50),Men = c(30,55,50))

df2019_melted <- melt(df2019)

ggplot(data = df2019_melted, aes(x = Institute, y = value, fill = variable))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")+
  labs(fill = "Gender")+
  xlab("Institute")+
  ylab("Percent")+
  scale_fill_discrete(labels = c("Women","Men"))+
  ggtitle("Overall Gender Composition 2019")
```

but I want the plot to show 2016 in faded bars, but grouped the same way as 2019, so 4 bars for each Institute.

Since the column names are the same for all of my dataframes I cant use rbind() or similar since it doesnt differentiate between what dataframe is what when combined.

[image: What each separate dataframe looks like when plotted]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a column for year to your data frames and then combine and melt. ggplot prefers everything to be in one data.frame

```
all_melted <- reshape2::melt(
  rbind(cbind(df2019, year=2019), cbind(df2016, year=2016)),
  id=c("year", "Institute"))
```

Then you can plot with something like this, mapping year to alpha to make "faded" bars

```
ggplot(all_melted, aes(x = Institute, y = value, fill = variable, alpha=factor(year)))+
  geom_col(position = "dodge")+
  labs(fill = "Gender")+
  xlab("Institute")+
  ylab("Percent")+
  scale_alpha_discrete(range=c(.4, 1), name="Year") + 
  ggtitle("Overall Gender Composition")
```

[image: Resulting Plot]